# Select yes if bigger no if smaller

Tags: mysql

Simple query: I want to include a column/field which says `Yes` when `SUM` field is larger than `yield` field and `No` when the other way around.

Mysql says I have an error in the query near (my whole query) and doesn't specify:

```
select *, IF(CONVERT(float,SUM) > CONVERT(float,yield),'Yes','No') from active_samples_w_seq where id > 100 and id < 200
```

Comment: Float is not a permitted type value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convertr. Maybe decimal would do. And although sum is not a reserved word (and won't cause a syntax error)  it is a function and I would escape it with backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanFromGermany said, the order is CONVERT(expr,type), but for float values you should use DECIMAL instead of FLOAT:

```
select *, IF(CONVERT(SUM,decimal) > CONVERT(yield,decimal),'Yes','No') 
from active_samples_w_seq 
where id > 100 and id < 200
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does ALWAYS yield at least an error code.

Your parameters in CONVERT are wrong, first you specify the field, then the type.

```
CONVERT(expr,type), CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: ... and I've never seen it don't yield a NEAR in the error message

Comment: Also when I put it like CONVERT(expr, type) it says:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'float) > CONVERT(yield,float),'Yes','No') from active_samples_w_seq where id > 1' at line 1